What is the difference in URDF file when a link is rotated instead of joint?
In
link 'left_wheel', I have mentioned rotation of 90 degree (1.57 radian) and in joint 'base_left_wheel' rotation is 0 degree.
Can someone explain me if I mention the rotation in joint 'base_left_wheel' as 90 degree and in link 'left_wheel' 0 degree what difference does it make? I m learning URDF, ROS.
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<robot name="mobile_robot">

    <material name="grey">
        <color rgba="0.7 0.7 0.7 1"/>
    </material>

    <link name="base_link">
        <visual>
            <geometry>
                <box size="0.6 0.4 0.2"/>
            </geometry>
            <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
            <material name="grey"/>
        </visual>
    </link>

    <link name ="left_wheel">
        <visual>
            <geometry>
                <cylinder radius="0.1" length="0.05" />
            </geometry>
            <origin xyz=" 0 0 0" rpy="1.57 0 0"/>
            <material name="grey" />
        </visual>
    </link>

    <joint name="base_left_wheel_joint" type="continuous">
        <parent link="base_link"/>
        <child link="left_wheel"/>
        <origin xyz="-0.15 0.225 -0.05" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        <axis xyz="0 1 0" />
    </joint>

</robot>

